# I keep getting this error when I shut down my app. Parcel: unknown type for value Color

Tags: android, kotlin, exception

I constantly get this exception when I close the application and open it back. So far I have not found a proper answer to this problem. Can someone come across this?

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                             Process: com.example.animeapp, PID: 3697
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parcel: unknown type for value Color(0.5647059, 0.28235295, 0.85490197, 1.0, sRGB IEC61966-2.1)
    at android.os.Parcel.getValueType(Parcel.java:2409)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2308)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:1382)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2460)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2316)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:1382)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2460)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2316)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:1233)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeMap(Parcel.java:1215)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2430)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2316)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:1233)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeMap(Parcel.java:1215)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2430)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2316)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:1382)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2460)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2316)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:1265)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1802)
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1389)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:1334)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2433)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2323)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:1265)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1802)
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1389)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:1334)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2433)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2323)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.dumpStats(BaseBundle.java:1874)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.dumpStats(BaseBundle.java:1911)
    at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:150)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

I tried to see what the problem is, and unfortunately all I found is that I need to write `@JvmField` somewhere, but it seems to me that this is not a solution to the problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.